We want to send cash to Banno institution customer accounts. Does Banno have any ACH wire APIs?
We run a rewards program and we were curious if Jack Henry offered any payment solutions that would make it easy for us to send cash directly into Banno customer bank accounts.

We would hold cash in our commercial checking account
We would like to send it to customers who earn rewards in our program
If a customer earns a reward, we would wire from our account the needed $ amount

I have read the documentation for Banno Digital Toolkit. I have not found anything to suggest the existence of payment rails.

You are correct, the Banno Digital Toolkit does not have payment rails endpoints.
Your best bet would be to explore a combination of jXchange and SymXchange.

If you're a client of JackHenry or using a JackHenry solution, then you would use their API, not Banno's.  Banno is just a consumer bank, and like any consumer bank should have a routing number and account number associated with the consumer account you want to credit.
It looks like Banno doesn't have their own technology stack, they use JackHenry as the technology service provider.  You can create an ACH Batch and Entries through the regular jack henry API.  Banno has some information links for this.
https://knowledge.banno.com/apps/business/business-banks-ach/
I wouldn't wire money, I would ACH everything.  If you're holding the cash in your originating account, then just issue the credit.  If you're needing to collect those funds from the client, you would Debit the client and then Credit the rewards beneficiary.
If you need the customer's bank account, I would also suggest using a Verification service to get that.  Plaid has a nice API that lets your clients provide OAuth authentication to get access to their banking details.
You would use a Wire if you think the risk of ACH Debiting the funds holder was greater than the cost and complexity of the wire call ( you don't wire to the rewards receiver, you wire to get the funds first -- if necessary ).
